# How can I smooth elements of a two-dimensional array with differing gaussian functions in python?

Tags: python, arrays, smoothing

How could I smooth the x[1,3] and x[3,2] elements of the array,

```
x = np.array([[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,1,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0]])
```

with two two-dimensional gaussian functions of width 1 and 2, respectively? In essence I need a function that allows me to smooth single "point like" array elements with gaussians of differing widths, such that I get an array with smoothly varying values.

Comment: have you looked at [gaussian filters](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.gaussian_filter.html)?

Comment: The general term you're looking for is [Convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution). Numpy can do it, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20036663/understanding-numpys-convolve

Comment: Do you want your resulting array to be 5x5?

Comment: Gaussian filters are pretty much exactly what I am looking for, thanks. However I can't see to determine how to apply gaussian functions with different sigma values to each pixel.. i.e. can you apply a array (5x5 array) of sigma using this function?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I am a little confused with the question you asked and the comments you have posted. It seems to me that you want to use [`scipy.ndimage.filters.gaussian_filter`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.gaussian_filter.html) but I don't understand what you mean by:

> [...] gaussian functions with different sigma values to each pixel. [...]

In fact, since you use a 2-dimensional array `x` the gaussian filter will have 2 parameters. The rule is: one sigma value per dimension rather than one sigma value per pixel.

Here is a short example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import scipy.ndimage

n = 200 # widht/height of the array
m = 1000 # number of points
sigma_y = 3.0
sigma_x = 2.0

# Create input array
x = np.zeros((n, n)) 
i = np.random.choice(range(0, n * n), size=m)
x[i / n, i % n] = 1.0

# Plot input array
pl.imshow(x, cmap='Blues', interpolation='nearest')
pl.xlabel("$x$")
pl.ylabel("$y$")
pl.savefig("array.png")

# Apply gaussian filter
sigma = [sigma_y, sigma_x]
y = sp.ndimage.filters.gaussian_filter(x, sigma, mode='constant')

# Display filtered array
pl.imshow(y, cmap='Blues', interpolation='nearest')
pl.xlabel("$x$")
pl.ylabel("$y$")
pl.title("$\sigma_x = " + str(sigma_x) + "\quad \sigma_y = " + str(sigma_y) + "$")
pl.savefig("smooth_array_" + str(sigma_x) + "_" + str(sigma_y) + ".png")
```

Here is the initial array:

[image]

Here are some results for different values of `sigma_x` and `sigma_y`:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

This allows to properly account for the influence of the second parameter of `scipy.ndimage.filters.gaussian_filter`.

However, according to the previous quote, you might be more interested in the assigement of different weights to each pixel. In this case, [scipy.ndimage.filters.convolve](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.convolve.html#scipy.ndimage.filters.convolve) is the function you are looking for. Here is the corresponding example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import scipy.ndimage

# Arbitrary weights
weights = np.array([[0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
                    [0, 2, 4, 2, 0],
                    [1, 4, 8, 4, 1],
                    [0, 2, 4, 2, 0],
                    [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]],
                   dtype=np.float)
weights = weights / np.sum(weights[:])
y = sp.ndimage.filters.convolve(x, weights, mode='constant')

# Display filtered array
pl.imshow(y, cmap='Blues', interpolation='nearest')
pl.xlabel("$x$")
pl.ylabel("$y$")
pl.savefig("smooth_array.png")
```

And the corresponding result:

[image]

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Compared to the isotropic Gaussian filter, What are the advantages of the anisotropic Gaussian filter?