# Confused by the indexing of a 3x3, two-dimensional convolution

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm confused by the indexing of the filter array for `scipy.ndimage.convolve`.

The simplest example, Identity works as I expected -- I get the same matrix back.

But I thought that a filter like:

```
0, 0, 0
0, 0, 1
0, 0, 0
```

Should give me the original matrix shifted one column left, with zero padding on the right edge.

Instead, the result is shifting the original matrix to the right, adding zero padding to the left column.

Similar results for the shifts in the other dimension.  Up seems down, and left seems right.

This makes me think I've got some fundamental misunderstanding about numpy indexing (which is quite possible) or what a convolution does (I think it's the sum of the products of each cell of the filter times the corresponding cell of the matrix, with the filter centered like a bullseye on the relevant cell of the matrix)

```
from scipy import ndimage

a = np.array([[1, 2, 0, 0],
              [5, 3, 7, 4],
              [0, 5, 1, 7],
              [9, 3, 0, 0]])

#k = np.array([[0,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,0]])   #identity

#expect: each cell in a' = its right neighbor in a
#actual: each cell in a' = its LEFT neighbor in a
k = np.array([[0,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,0,0]])  

cvo = ndimage.convolve(a, k, mode='constant', cval=0.0)

cvo
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding NumPy's Convolve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20036663/understanding-numpys-convolve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is just a little difference between **convolution** ans **cross-correlation** (in which you are a bit confused).

Given a matrix and a filter:

> If you multiply the filter as it is to the (corresponding cells of)
> matrix and then take the sum, then it is **cross-correlation**.

> If you multiply the mirror image (up and down) of filter to
> the (corresponding cells of) matrix and then take the sum, then it is
> **convolution**.

[image]

**SciPy** goes as per the original definition, hence it gives such (correct) results (which you were not expecting).

When it comes to **Deep-Learning/ Neural Networks**, in that, the convolutions used has an argument `flip_filters = True` (maybe with different names in different libraries). So, here (in Deep Learning) they actually does cross-correlation.

To know more: [Convolution Vs Correlation](https://towardsdatascience.com/convolution-vs-correlation-af868b6b4fb5), [What's the difference between convolution and crosscorrelation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/353272/whats-the-difference-between-convolution-and-crosscorrelation)